# Win32 - Contents in tab control disappearing when dragged off screen

Tags: c, winapi, tabs

I am using resources with Win32 to create a dialog containing a single tab control. The tab works fine when changing tabs but somehow dragging the window off screen ( eg. dragging it past bottom of screen then back up ) will cause the tab contents to disappear. I think it may be a problem with how I've set the clipping properties but after much fiddling I still didn't get it working exactly how I expect.

I have uploaded a basic skeleton project here which has the bare minimum required to reproduce this problem and would be very grateful if someone could check it out.

http://localhostr.com/file/nPTbTTQ/skeleton.rar

Comment: does it have the same refresh problem if you drag another window over your app?  It sounds like our app isn't handling WM_PAINT messages correctly.  In Win32, the windows don't remember what's been drawn on them.  Instead, any time a portion (or all) of your window becomes invalidated, like when you drag it off the screen, win32 will send WM_PAINT and ask the app to redraw.  Usually if you just have controls, each one will redraw itself, but maybe something in your code intercepts WM_PAINT so it doesn't get to the right controls?  Just guesses, didn't have time to look at your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Z-order problem, the dialog is *behind* the tab control.  Change the parent of the inner dialog from hwndDlg to hwndTab.  I don't want to guess why you saw the static control text at all.

Comment: You shouldnt actually do this. Tab controls are purposely hollow. Property sheets use the main dialog as the parent for all the pages, and just hide and show the relevant page. WS_CLIPSIBLINGS should not as a result be used with either tab controls or group boxes.